# Trying to read off a list from a text file, then search the text file, and extract a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, find

So right now I'm trying to write a program that takes a user inputted date, like this : 02/04/1992, and outputs the date like this: April 2nd, 1992. Instead of having corresponding dates just as strings or something else in the program, I have a text file that has the dates in a list like this:

01January

02February

03March

.. and so on.

I know I have to use string.find(), but I'm not sure what the parameters I should use. So far I have this:

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string thedate; //string to enter the date
    string month; // this string will hold the month
    ifstream myfile ("months.txt");
    cout << "Please enter the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy, include the slashes: " << endl;
    cin >> thedate;

    month = thedate.substr( 3, 2 );
    string newmonth;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( myfile.good() )
        {
            getline (myfile,newmonth);

            cout << newmonth.find() << endl;

        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

    return 0;
}
```

I've checked the find function online but I still don't understand what parameters I would use. Right now in my program, the month in the format mm is stored inside the string month; I can't figure out how to search the text file for what is inside month;, and return the rest of that line. For example, 05 would become May. I also haven't learned arrays yet, so if I could stay away from those it would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) explains the parameters of `std::string::find()` quite well.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Im new to programming, so I dont really understand what std :: npos, etc. means in their code? Either way, I couldnt see anything that explains how to search for something using a string as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use find.

```
while ( myfile.good() )
{
    getline (myfile,newmonth);
    if ( newmonth.substr(0,2) == month) {
        cout << newmonth.substr(2) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude thanks a lot. Just to understand what is going on there, since there its going through a whole list, is it the if statement that is trying to match each line in the text file with month?

Comment: yes, if you sure first 2 letter is digits, and user input two digits, it's enough to compare strings, or you can compare after converting string to integer by atoi.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd organize things a bit differently. I'd read in the whole file (apparently 12 lines) at the beginning, using the number to determine the spot in an array at which to store the associated string. Then when the user enters a date, you just use their number to index into that array without search for it.

```
int number;
std::string tmp;

std::vector<std::string> month_names(12);

while (myfile >> number) {
   myfile >> tmp;
   month_names[number] = tmp;
};

std::string get_name(int month) { 
    return month_names[month];
}
```